# Getter and setter extension methods

Tags: dart, extension-methods, getter-setter

How can I add getter and setter extension methods as per below? The below doesn't work because `_foo` isn't defined and setting to `foo` directly like `set foo(val) => foo = val;` creates an infinite loop.

```dart
extension on Uri {
  String get foo => _foo;
  set foo(val) => _foo = val;
}

main() {
  var uri = Uri();
  uri.foo = 'bar';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with getter/setter methods.  You would have the same problem with *any* extension method.  Fundamentally your problem is that you want to add a data member to an object *instance*, but that isn't something that static extension methods can do.  You maybe could have your methods lookup `this` on some global [`Expando`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Expando-class.html) instance, but make sure you read the caveats about using `Expando`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store *data* on the `Uri` object, you need a place to store it.
You can't declare extension fields *because* extensions don't change the class they extend, so they can't add storage to the object.

What you can do is use an [`Expando`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Expando-class.html):

```dart
extension on Uri {
  static final _storage = Expando<String>();
  String get foo => _storage[this];
  set foo(String value) {
    _storage[this] = value;
  }
}
```

An `Expando` is intended for adding storage "on the side" for any object without leaking storage when the objects get garbage collected.
(You can't use it to store values on strings, numbers, booleans or `null`, because those are special wrt. identity because you can create them from *literals*, ... and because in JavaScript they aren't real objects).